# What is right way to implement "count" method on raw MongoDB protocol?

Tags: mongodb, network-protocols

I have read [MongoDB Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) and implementing my own driver.

I'm trying to implement "count" method which returns number of documents that meet the conditions in collection.
But in above manual, I could not find opcode which suitable for count method.

It is possible that getting all desired documents by executing OP_QUERY and count them in driver code. But it looks so inefficient(unnecessary contents in documents will be sent on network).

Can I implement "count" method efficiently in other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

I have created mongo-proxy script which proxies MongoDB protocol and run it between MongoDB server and standard mongo client program.

As the result of that, I confirmed request message are sent as follows.

commands:

```
> use test-db
> db.TestCollection.find({'a': 1}).count()
3
```

messages:

```
===== client -> server =====
type: OP_QUERY
full_collection_name: test-db.$cmd
query: {'count': 'TestCollection', 'query': {'a': 1.0}, 'fields': {}}

===== server -> client =====
{'n': 3.0, 'ok': 1.0}
```

I could get count value from test-db.$cmd collection.
:-)